# Several ways to use pthread_create with a member function of a C ++ class: Error when function has input parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am testing different ways of executing as a thread a function defined in a C ++ class using pthread_create.

The program that I attach as an example compile and works correctly in these cases:

- If the function is static: ThRoutine1
- If the function is friend: ThRoutine2
- If the function is neither static nor friend and has no parameters, an intermediate function can be used: runThRoutine3 and ThRoutine3

I compile the program with the command:

```
g ++ -Wall -g example_program.cpp -lpthread -o example_program
```

However, I can not create a thread with the ThRoutine4 function that is neither static nor friend and has an input parameter.

After reading several posts on various forums, I have tried to define the s_param structure and the unThRoutine4 function, but when compiling the program I get these errors (it is necessary to uncomment the lines that appear commented):

```
example_program.cpp: In static member function ‘static void * MyClass :: runThRoutine4 (void *)’:
example_program.cpp: 44: 34: error: ‘class MyClass’ has no member named ‘ptr’
       return ((MyClass *) bundle) -> ptr-> ThRoutine4 (bundle-> number);
                                  ^
example_program.cpp: 44: 56: error: ‘void *’ is not a pointer-to-object type
       return ((MyClass *) bundle) -> ptr-> ThRoutine4 (bundle-> number);
```

I appreciate any help in this regard.

**The source code of example_program.cpp is:**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define _REENTRANT


typedef void* (*THREAD_FUNC_PTR)(void *);

struct s_param
{
  void  *ptr;
  int   number;
};

class MyClass
{
  public:
    static void *ThRoutine1 (int number)
    {
      printf("Hello form ThRoutine1 theard. Number = %d\n", number);
    }

    friend void *ThRoutine2 (int number);

    void *ThRoutine3 ()
    {
      printf("Hello form ThRoutine3 theard.\n");
    }

    static void *runThRoutine3 (void *context)
    {
        return ((MyClass *)context)->ThRoutine3();
    }

    void *ThRoutine4 (int number)
    {
      printf("Hello form ThRoutine4 theard. Number = %d\n", number);
    }

    // It is necessary to uncomment this function to get the indicated errors.
    //
    // static void *runThRoutine4(void *bundle)
    // {
    //  return((MyClass *)bundle)->ptr->ThRoutine4(bundle->number);
    //}

};



void *ThRoutine2 (int number)
{
  printf("Hello form ThRoutine2 theard. Number = %d\n", number);
}


int main(void)
{
  int t = 1;
  pthread_t tid[4]; // an array to keep track of the threads
  MyClass cppClass;

  pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,(THREAD_FUNC_PTR)&cppClass.ThRoutine1,(int *)t++);

  pthread_create(&tid[2],NULL,(THREAD_FUNC_PTR)&ThRoutine2,(int *)t++);

  pthread_create(&tid[3], NULL, &MyClass::runThRoutine3, &cppClass);

  // It is necessary to uncomment this source code line to get the indicated errors.
  //
  // pthread_create(&tid[4], NULL, &MyClass::runThRoutine4, &cppClass);


  printf("Parent is running.\n");
  sleep(10);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just was about to fix OPs code but then I stopped and restarted:

1. There is a lot of C code which would be done different in C++.
2. It feels very wrong to fiddle with the `pthread_create()` because there is already a nice wrapper with [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

While fiddling with OPs code I noticed a lot of other weaknesses which even should be an issue in C as well like e.g. functions with a non-`void` return type but no `return` statement in body.

So, this is what I got after rewriting OPs code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

class MyClass
{
  public:
    static void ThRoutine1 (int number)
    {
      std::ostringstream out;
      out << "Hello from ThRoutine1 thread. Number = " << number << '\n';
      std::cout << out.str();
    }

    friend void ThRoutine2 (int number);

    void ThRoutine3(int number)
    {
      std::ostringstream out;
      out << "Hello from ThRoutine3 thread. Number = " << number << '\n';
      std::cout << out.str();
    }

#if 0 // Oops. It's nearly identical to ThRoutine3() now...
    void ThRoutine4 (int number)
    {
      std::ostringstream out;
      out << "Hello from ThRoutine4 thread. Number = " << number << '\n';
      std::cout << out.str();
    }
#endif // 0

};

void ThRoutine2 (int number)
{
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << "Hello from ThRoutine2 thread. Number = " << number << '\n';
  std::cout << out.str();
}

int main()
{
  int t = 1;
  std::thread threads[3];
  MyClass cppClass;
  threads[0] = std::thread(&MyClass::ThRoutine1, t++);
  threads[1] = std::thread(&ThRoutine2, t++);
  threads[2] = std::thread(&MyClass::ThRoutine3, &cppClass, t++);
  
  std::cout << "Parent is running.\n";
#if 0 // Waiting a while is not a reliable synchronization...
  sleep(10);
#else // ...but join is:
  for (std::thread &thread : threads) {
    if (thread.joinable()) thread.join();
  }
#endif // 0
}
```

Output:

```
Parent is running.
Hello from ThRoutine2 thread. Number = 2
Hello from ThRoutine1 thread. Number = 1
Hello from ThRoutine3 thread. Number = 3
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73995b76ac6c745d)

**Notes:**

1. I removed `MyClass::ThRoutine4()` after I realized that this was already covered by `MyClass::ThRoutine3()` (which I modified slightly to “follow the general pattern”).
2. I replaced C-ish `printf()` by C++ stream output. Please, note, that C++ stream output is thread-safe. However, composing output with stream operators (`<<`) may cause a mixing of outputs from multiple threads. (I noticed this in my first version.) This could be fixed by introducing a mutex – or even simpler by pre-composing the output in a `std::stringstream`.
3. When I was about to replace the `sleep()` by `std::this_thread::sleep()` I became aware that OP used this as kind of synchronization. Please, note: **Time (or delay) is an unreliable synchronization for threads.** So, I replaced this with a [thread::join()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join).
4. My original intention was to demonstrate as well how nicely lambdas can be used for adapters (to fit a certain function into a required signature). While implementing I realized that the [std::thread::thread()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) is expressive enough to cover all cases of OP without lambda-adapters.

---

I thought a while whether it's a reasonable answer to solve OPs issue with `pthread_create()` using `std::thread` instead. IMHO, it is.

1. `std::thread` is *the* C++ wrapper for `pthread`s on systems where `pthread` is supported.
2. On platforms (e.g. Windows / Visual Studio) where there is something else than `pthread`, the `std::thread` will wrap something else. So, the same code can be compiled without any modification.

   [**Live Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/vvaqcc)
3. The techniques OP tried to use feel somehow familiar to me. The reason is that I started Object Oriented Programming in C (a long time ago) and switched to C++ later. Thereby, I carried (my) common C techniques into my C++ code and needed a while to switch to more idiomatic C++ code (after realizing that I started to fight against windmills).

Comment: Thanks, your code works right. But I am interested on use thread_create and not std::thread. What modifications would need to be made to the code for pthread_create to work with ThRoutine4?

Comment: @jstechg And nothing in my longish answer was able to convince you that this is "fighting against windmills"? :-(

Comment: @jstechg I fixed your sample: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1929535c193c63cc). However, all that still feels _very wrong_ (although I made the most compiler complaints silent). ;-)

Comment: @jstechg Passing an `int` where a `void*` is expected, I have last seen in a X11 / OSF/Motif sample source code - round about 20 years ago. (64 bit was still future at that time while 32 bit was "state of the art".) Please, note that the sample runs (in my case) on 64 bit platform where `sizeof (int) != sizeof (void*)`. This is U.B. and crying for more issues...

Comment: Thanks, your answers solve my doubts in order to implement it using pthread_create and in future projects I will use std: thread

Comment: @jstechg If this answer was a help then would you mind to accept it? (I invested a not-too-small time into writing this.)